# KafkaProducer.doSend: Double invocation of Partitioner causes unequal distribution

Tags: spring, apache-kafka

Versions:

- Spring boot: 2.4.1
- Kafka-clients: 2.6.0

Due some system limitations Kafka Producer is configured to send each message separately. Specifically, batches are disabled by setting `linger.ms = 0` and `max.batch.size = 0`.
Therefore, each message is new batch from Kafka's client perspective. I want to distribute messages equally between all available partitions, that's why I configured client `RoundRobinPartitioner` to achieve it.

However, testing on configuration when one node is down and I have even number of partitions, I figured out that messages are distributed between half of all available partitions. The reason for such behaviour is double invocation of `partitioner.partition(..)` in `KafkaProducer.doSend(..)`'. Since `RoundRobinPartitioner.partition()` under the hood increments counter  and returns its remainder of the division by available partitions number, calling it twice within one record publish causes skipping of each second partition.

For instance, availablePartitions contains 6 partitions (1-6). Calling `partition(..)` twice through `KafkaProducer.doSend(..)` always skip 1,3,5 partitions.

```
 private Future<RecordMetadata> doSend(ProducerRecord<K, V> record, Callback callback) {
 ..
 int partition = partition(record, serializedKey, serializedValue, cluster);
 ..
 RecordAccumulator.RecordAppendResult result = accumulator.append(tp, timestamp, serializedKey,
                serializedValue, headers, interceptCallback, remainingWaitMs, true, nowMs);

//Since I disabled batches this if is always true
        if (result.abortForNewBatch) {
            int prevPartition = partition;
            partitioner.onNewBatch(record.topic(), cluster, prevPartition);
            partition = partition(record, serializedKey, serializedValue, cluster);
            tp = new TopicPartition(record.topic(), partition);
            if (log.isTraceEnabled()) {
                log.trace("Retrying append due to new batch creation for topic {} partition {}. The old partition was {}", record.topic(), partition, prevPartition);
            }
            // producer callback will make sure to call both 'callback' and interceptor callback
            interceptCallback = new InterceptorCallback<>(callback, this.interceptors, tp);

            result = accumulator.append(tp, timestamp, serializedKey,
                serializedValue, headers, interceptCallback, remainingWaitMs, false, nowMs);
        }
```

1. While it's easy to reimplement, I wonder whether this behaviour is
   desired?
2. What are the reasons to update partition if current batch
   is closed?
3. I'm confident that I'm not the first, How community
   overcomes this design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround `UniformStickyPartitioner` can be used. It does exactly what's needed: selects new partition only on `newBatch(..)` call whereas multiple calls to `partition(..)` produce the same output. The only difference between real Round Robin mechanism is UniformStickyPartitioner strategy is that partition is calculated as randomInt % availablePartitions. However, the distribution would still be rather equal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I came across this issue before, which made me confusing for a long time.

There are little answers on Google about this, and Kafka community have not fixed this.

But there are related discussions on `Apache Jira`:

[KAFKA-13303](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-13303)

[KAFKA-9965](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9965)

[KAFKA-9964](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9964)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31441032)